# Why does this SQL return an incorrect result set?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables; a population data table, county table, and a state table. When I run the SQL below I get an incorrect result set. The SQL returns 55 counties in Wisconsin. I know there are 72 in the state. When I go to the Counties table and run the single-line SELECT statement below, I get 72 counties.

I'm also getting multiples of the same county but with different population details, which to me indicates a problem with the join statements. I think I tried all the combinations of join statements but have been unable to resolve the problem. Using one combination of joins I was able to a result set returned with 86 counties. That is also wrong.

Thanks!

-- returns correct counties.
`SELECT * FROM counties WHERE stateId = 'D14B7CD0-145F-4B84-9533-0BB3B2F5A5B5'`

```
-- returns incorrect counties.
SELECT this.POPULATION, this.LATITUDE, this.LONGITUDE, this.CountyId, st.NAME AS StateName, cty.Name AS CountyName
FROM PopulationData AS this
INNER JOIN Counties AS cty ON this.CountyId = cty.Id
INNER JOIN States AS st ON cty.StateId = st.Id
WHERE (st.Name = 'wisconsin')
ORDER BY CountyName
```

Comment: Samples of your data and both result sets would help. You have not provided enough data for an answer to be given.

Comment: The latter query join two more table so looks like some countries (17) has no relations in populationData or states tables

Comment: Does your PopulationData table contain a single row for each county?

If there are counties with no corresponding row in PopulationData, they will not be returned by your query ... if there are counties with multiple rows in PopulationData, they will return multiple rows in your query.

Comment: The query looks fine. Probably your data's screwy. Check that all of your Wisconsin counties are attached to the proper state. If your database collation is case sensitive, make sure you don't have a `Wisconsin` and `wisconsin` and `WiScOnSin` type thing going either.

Comment: I would like to say that I love the idea of using a GUID for StateId...

Comment: @weekendWarrior - ya like that? Sometimes we're stuck with what we inherit. You should know that.

Comment: @SpecialAgent_W436: Obviously

Answer (score 2):

The latter query join two more table so looks like some countries (17) has no relations in populationData or states tables

Try out

```
SELECT 
      this.POPULATION, 
      this.LATITUDE, 
      this.LONGITUDE, 
      this.CountyId, 
      st.NAME AS StateName, 
      cty.Name AS CountyName
FROM Counties AS cty
LEFT JOIN  PopulationData AS this ON this.CountyId = cty.Id
LEFT JOIN States AS st ON cty.StateId = st.Id
WHERE (st.Name IS NULL OR st.Name = 'wisconsin')
ORDER BY CountyName
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the data in your PopulationData table is correct? If you have incorrect population to County mappings, then you will get bad resulst.

And if the first works correctly using stateId, why don't you try using that stateId instead of name in the one that isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

With this type of issue you have to break down your problem into smaller pieces to figure out where the problem is.

Your query looks valid so it's something to do with the data.

Try using left joins as silev suggested, then turn them into inner joins one by one and you'll see which restriction you're adding is causing the issue.

My guess is there isn't data in PopulationData for all the counties. If you want to still see those counties listed even if there is no data in PopulationData put States first, do inner join with Counties, then left join with PopulationData.

Answer (score 1):

Returns correct counties with null values in the fields from tables that can't be joined.

```
SELECT this.POPULATION, this.LATITUDE, this.LONGITUDE, this.CountyId, st.NAME AS StateName, cty.Name AS CountyName
FROM Counties AS cty
LEFT JOIN States AS st ON this.CountyId = cty.Id
LEFT JOIN PopulationData AS this ON cty.StateId = st.Id
WHERE cty.stateId = 'D14B7CD0-145F-4B84-9533-0BB3B2F5A5B5'
ORDER BY CountyName
```